# In angular2 how can I redirect a user if they are not logged in, so they dont reach logged in views components code?

Tags: angular

In angular2 how can I redirect a user if they are not logged in, so they dont reach logged in views components code?

I dont want the component to be hit.
I want the user to be redirect to homepage if not authenticated.

Is there a way I can do this in my app.ts file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CanActivate` guard to check if the user is logged in before navigate to a route.

Create an `guard.service.js`:

```
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    //Here check if the user is logged in
    return isLoggedIn;
  }
```

Now import the AuthGuard class, and use the `AuthGuard` in your routing component:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: OnlyForLoggedInUsers,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

Here you can find further details about implemeting the canActivate guard:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: what version of the router is this? Will it work with this version that I have: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1"

Comment: So will this actually work if I wire this up to the routes: 

{
  path: 'admin',
  component: CrisisAdminComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},

Comment: canActivate doesnt work with my current version of the router which is : @angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1  I dont get errors but the code doesnt fire either